# _typeError 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter, dart

Hope all is well,
Each and every thing is good before updating dart.
now I am facing _typeError.
Here is my Script.

```
Stepe 1.



 getAllSlider() async {
        var slider = await _sliderService.getSlider();
        //var result = json.encode(slider.body);
        var result = json.decode(slider.body);
        result['data'].forEach((data) {
          setState(() {
            items.add(NetworkImage(data['image_path']));
          });
        });
      }
```

Step 2

```
 body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            carouselSlider(items),
]
));
```

Step 3
Here at point  images: items getting Exception error

Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List')

```
Widget carouselSlider(items) => SizedBox(
      height: 200.0,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Carousel(
            boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
            images: items,
            autoplay: true,
            animationDuration: Duration(microseconds: 10000),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Where and how did you define items? just in case make sure is List<Widget> items = [] or in carouselSlider pass it as List<Widgets items and not a dynamic items, maybe that way you will see where is the error

Comment: Here I am define var items = [];

Comment: define it like var items = <Widget>[];

Comment: Now getting error Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Widget')

Comment: the property images in Carousel expects a list of Strings or Widget? you should consider checking https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems nad use proper type where possible

Comment: Try with specific type =>     Widget carouselSlider(List<NetworkImage> items)=> SizedBox(..... .);

Comment: remove `<Widget>` from your ListView children since your List is dynamic. So instead of `ListView(children: <Widget>[]);` do this: `ListView (children: []);`

Comment: TexV@ not working